# "Delayed Recovery" talent in Witcher 3

Tags: the-witcher-3

The "Delayed Recovery" talent in Witcher 3 reads as follows if you put 3 talent points into it: "Potion effects don't wear off until potion Toxicity falls to 70% of the maximum level."

I've tried this and either it's not working or (more likely) I am misunderstanding something. Consuming 3 Decoctions puts me on 75% Toxicity so whether the toxicity of an additional potion wears off or not the talent should make the effect of the potion run as long as those decoctions keep me above 70%. However, consuming a swallow (for example) has the exact same duration and effect as if I didn't run this talent - after the usual potion duration of swallow the effect wears off even though I'm far above 70% at all times. How does this talent work exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to  [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/witcher/comments/373cup/the_delayed_recovery_alchemy_talent_is_useless_if/):

> I thought I could just get up 50%+ toxicity by using decoctions and then have an easy time staying above 70% but unfortunately this isn't the case, **all the toxicity has to come from potions**

I think this was intended by devs, otherwise you could abuse this skill by having powerful potions always up.

Comment: And it does say "potion Toxicity" in the message, too.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the the calculation is based on potion toxicity only. Using decoctions will make it impossible for this to work.

Comment: call me a stickler, but where's you source information for this? At the moment just seems like a sentence without much ground to stand on